# Getting R to assume/guess names of list elements

Tags: r, list, names

When constructing a `list()`, particularly large ones, I would like to find a way to get R to guess the name of the elements being passed to the list, based on the name of the element itself.

For example, to construct a list with the following data:

```
dog <- c(1,2,3)
cat <- c(3,2,1)
```

With names I currently have to write:

```
list(dog = dog, cat = cat)
```

Is there a way to simply write:

```
list(dog, cat)
```

where the names of the element are automatically guessed based on the element name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mget` with `ls()` if these are the only objects in the global environment

```
mget(ls())
```

If the global environment have other variables as well, then another clean option is to create a new env, and objects created in that env, then it would be easier to call `ls` with `envir` specified

```
e1 <- new.env()
e1$dog <- 1:3
e1$cat <- 3:1
mget(ls(envir = e1))
```

---

If we use `lst` from `purrr`, it would automatically get the identifiers as well

```
library(purrr)
lst(dog, cat)
#$dog
#[1] 1 2 3

#$cat
#[1] 3 2 1
```